# What is the analogue of the rotation matrix in polar coordinates?

Tags: rotations, spherical-coordinates

In cartesian coordinates, a rotation around the z axis is represented as:

$$\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
\cos\phi & \sin\phi & 0\\
-\sin\phi & \cos\phi & 0\\
0&0&1
\end{array} \right)$$
What is the analogue in spherical coordinates?

**EDIT**
My change of coordinates is:

$x=r \sin\theta\cos\phi$

$y=r \sin\theta\sin\phi$

$z=r \cos\theta$

Comment: Perhaps that you just add a constant to the angle $\varphi$?

Comment: @MattiP. But in spherical coordinates a vector is represented in the basis $$\left(\begin{array}{c} r\\ \theta\\ \phi \end{array}\right)$$ this confuses me.

Comment: I started to write out an answer, but realized that there are too many conventions that are ambiguous here. For example, your rotation is clockwise as viewed looking down the $z$-axis towards the origin, sending positive $+x \mapsto -y$ and $+y \mapsto +x$ for $\phi = +\frac{\pi}{2}$, which is the reverse of the standard convention.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the explicit change-of-coordinates from spherical to cartesian that you're using, i.e. give each of $x$, $y$, and $z$ in terms of $r$, $\theta$, and $\phi$.

Comment: @SammyBlack I have edited the question as required

Comment: @mattiav27 I agree with Matti P. In spherical coordinates, it is a translation that only changes the third coordinate. By the way, would you replace $\phi$ in the matrix by a different letter? Now, you have the same notation for two different objects, which is confusing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We wish to rotate a vector $\vec{r}$ to $R\vec{r}$ for a suitable rotation matrix $R$. I should make an important conceptual correction: the correct representation of $\vec{r}$ is $r\hat{r}$, not $r\hat{r}+\theta\hat{\theta}+\phi\hat{\phi}$ or whatever you were thinking of. [In particular](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_coordinate_system#Integration_and_differentiation_in_spherical_coordinates)$$\begin{align}\hat{r}&=\sin\theta\cos\phi\hat{i}+\sin\theta\sin\phi\hat{j}+\cos\theta\hat{k},\\\hat{\theta}&=\cos\theta\cos\phi\hat{i}+\cos\theta\sin\phi\hat{j}-\sin\theta\hat{k},\\\hat{\phi}&=-\sin\phi\hat{i}+\cos\phi\hat{j}\end{align}$$is our orthonormal basis. We can write these equations as $\hat{S}_A=T_{Aa}\hat{C}_a$ (I [sum over repeated indices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_notation)), with $\hat{C}_a$ ($\hat{S}_A$) the Cartesian (spherical) basis vectors, e.g. $T_{ri}=\sin\theta\cos\phi$. Now you just want to compute $R_{AB}=T_{Aa}R_{ab}(T^{-1})_{bB}$, or in matrix terms $R^\text{spherical}=TR^\text{Cartesian}T^{-1}$; I'll leave that to you.

Answer (score 0):

In coordinates $(r, \theta, \varphi)$, the transformation is

$(r, \theta, \varphi) \mapsto (r, \theta, \varphi + \phi)$

which is not linear (clearly, it does not map 0 to 0 for non-zero $\phi$); it is an affine transformation of a 3-space.  To represent an affine transformation as linear, the affine space $A$ in question (our 3-space) is canonically embedded into a universal vector space $V$ (think $\dim V = 1 + \dim A$, and $0 \notin A$).  Point $(r, \theta, \varphi) \in A$ corresponds to vector $(r, \theta, \varphi, 1) \in V$.  Your rotation matrix is then a matrix of a shift operator in $V$:

$$
\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
1 && 0 && 0 && 0 \\
0 && 1 && 0 && 0 \\
0 && 0 && 1 && \phi \\
0 && 0 && 0 && 1 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

A general rotation in $n$-space will look the same: rotation angles placed between 0 and 1 in the last column.  The case $n=2$ is easy to visualize in its entirety, together with the embedding into the universal space.