# Confusion about spherical coordinates

Tags: spherical-coordinates

[This answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3967897/249710) to my [previous post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3967853/249710) confuses me: I have always thought about spherical coordinates as a triad of mutually orthogonal vectors $\hat{r},\hat{\theta},\hat{\phi}$ disposed as in the following figure copied from [here](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/SphericalCoordinates.html)

[image]

but the answer says that the correct representation of a vector $\vec{r}$ is $r \hat{r}$, not something like this:

$$\left(\begin{array}{c}
r\\
\theta\\
\phi
\end{array}\right)$$

Can anyone explain in a simple way where my *interpretation* is wrong?

Comment: Seems like this should have been a comment on the answer that you already accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The vector $\vec{r} = x \hat{x} + y \hat{y} + z \hat{z}$ tells you how to go from the origin to the point $(x,y,z)$. And that's the same thing as going $r$ steps from the origin in the $\hat{r}$ direction, right?

Here $r=r(x,y,z)=\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}$ of course, and “the $\hat{r}$ direction” means $\hat{r}(x,y,z)$, the $\hat{r}$ direction associated with that specific point $(x,y,z)$. You could write the formula as
$$
\vec{r}(x,y,z) = r(x,y,z) \, \hat{r}(x,y,z)
$$
to make this clearer.

Comment: And what about the other two vectors $\hat{\theta}$ and $\hat{\phi}$ of the figure? What do they represent?

Comment: Well, they just represent other directions (the directions in which the point $(x,y,z)$ will move when you increase $\theta$ or $\phi$, respectively). Any vector can be written as a unique linear combination of $\hat{r}(x,y,z)$, $\hat{\phi}(x,y,z)$ and $\hat{\theta}(x,y,z)$ (for any given point $(x,y,z)$ not on the $z$ axis). But for the particular vector $\vec{r}(x,y,z)$ you only need $\hat{r}(x,y,z)$.